# Decrypt a String encoded using AES 256

Tags: android, encryption, aes

Totally security noob here.

I have to decrypt a String I receive, encoded in Base64. All I have is the String I need to decrypt, and a String, which the service that sents me the String to decode calls it a seed.

Based on what I have read here and in other places, I have this:

```
public String decrypt(String message) throws Exception
{
    String salt = "PRUEBA";
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(message.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    String decoded=new String(Base64.decode(decryptedValue,Base64.DEFAULT));
    return decoded;
}
```

This returns java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.

I tried also [this](https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android) library, but it returns IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Don't know if I need something else from the server side, as I said I have little to no knowledge of encryption.

I am completely lost at this issue. Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: String salt = "PRUEBA", the slat is nothing but the key used for encrypting or decrypting. It should be length of 128 / 256 bytes.

Comment: You need more information to have any hope here. You need to know details about how the data was encrypted, more details than you have, and you obviously must be able to get or recover the same key. Perhaps the key was derived from a password? If so, you need the details of the password-based derivation method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code and you are missing some critical information (you may ask from the system sending data)

You are missing Cipher, IV (optionally) and key

> Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

Using only `AES` cipher with no IV parameter means you are using `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` cipher. Are you sure you suppose to use this cipher? Shouldn't it be `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` ? Ask the system doing the encryption what the encryption should be (including mode and padding). Knowing it's AES may not be sufficient.

If the mode used needs IV (initialization vector), you need to know its value. Usually IV is 128 bits (16 bytes) prepended to the ciphertext, but  you need to know that for sure.

> String salt = "PRUEBA"; 
>   SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");

And - **you need a key** (without the key you won't decrypt).

As already commented, the key needs to be 128, 192 or 256 bits long (=16, 24 or 32 bytes). If it is to be generated from another string, you need to know how.

> String decryptedValue = new String(decValue); 
>   String decoded=new String(Base64.decode(decryptedValue,Base64.DEFAULT));

Are you sure that the decrypted value is base64 encoding of another String?

Just to get some examples for Java crypto, you may have a loot at my [blog](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) too.

Comment: Agree with Gusto2, you need the initial vector and the key. And the key is not the salt (it is just some bits that add complexity if you want to guess the key).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I know I need more info, and can stop bashing my head against a wall.